# Git: how to move a branch between repositories

Tags: git, github

Here is my situation: I have cloned a master branch from a repository and created a local branch to make the changes. After a few days working I tried to push this local branch I have created so the team could also work on it. Then I realized that I don't have the permission to push to this repository, so I created a fork and a branch so I can push my changes.

Now I want to move this branch to my fork and keep it saved in the same place. The really ideal scenario would be just point this fork branch to the exiting location.

I'm using sourcetree and bitbucket

How can I do that?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Git is a distributed version control system. So you can have the same repo in multiple locations. When you first clone a repo locally, you have your own copy with a "remote" called origin (see it typing `git remote -v`). You simply need to add the second fork you created as a second remote:

`git remote add other git@host.com:foo/bar.git`

In the previous command "other" is just a name for the remote, so later you can do: `git push other master` (push my local master to other's master) or `git push other local_branch:remote_branch`

The possibilities are endless, you can pull/push from any remote's branches to any local branches.

Git has a book available for free hosted on their site: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2. It's a great start for everyone, it was for me a while back.

Comment: I'd also add Atlassian's "[forking workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow)" explanation.  We use "upstream" for the corporate repository and "origin" for our own personal fork.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to keep my answer agnostic of where the git repositories are hosted. But yeah, the default name is "origin" when cloning, everything else is up to the user or best practices the user follows.

Comment: *"other" is just a name for the remote.* `git push origin feature_branch:feature_branch` eh?