# git copy specific branch into other specific branch in a new repository

Tags: eclipse, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a git repository B which contains ver_3 branch. I want to COPY this branch to git repository A to ver_1 branch.

Is there a way to do it through SourceTree?
If not how can I copy the specific branch as other branch ?

Thanks,Hila

Comment: Not sure of source tree, but this might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751928/git-how-to-move-a-branch-between-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the answer that [divyesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364365/git-copy-specific-branch-into-other-specific-branch-in-a-new-repository/43365535#comment73790512_43364365) linked to to in their comment, you need to add the other repo as a remote and push the branch to it.

To add a remote in Sourcetree:

1. Open *repository B*
2. In the top menu bar click Repository > Settings
3. Click Add
4. Enter the details of *repository A* and click OK

To push the branch:

1. In the list of branches in the left panel right click *ver_3*
2. Go to *Push to >* then select *repository A*
3. In the dialog that appears, under the *Remote branch* column, edit the name of the branch to *ver_1*
4. Click Push

Using a GUI for Git can be really helpful - I use Sourcetree myself. However, it is always worth familiarising yourself with the actual Git commands to ensure you understand what the GUI is doing for you.

Comment: It seems in your explanation that we move the branch? I want to copy it.

Comment: Why do you think it would be 'moved'?

Git has a distributed architecture meaning the repo on your machine is the same as the one on the 'server'. If your colleague gave you access, you could add the repo on their machine as a remote too!

By adding repo A as a remote and pushing the branch to it, you simply write the data to that repo. The state of your local repo and the origin remote remain unchanged.

Once you've pushed the branch to repo A, you can remove the remote you just added and everything is as it was before except repo A now has a branch ver_1 that it didn't have before.